# Minimal WordPress load for only `get_option` to work (because ajax...)

Tags: ajax, performance, optimization, options

In a plugin, I use ajax to `get_option()` which takes much longer than it has to because entire wp gets loaded.

How do I set things up so that it (my ajax) loads only what is needed? (`get_option()`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're building something for public consumption (a plugin, a theme, etc) use [`admin-ajax.php` like you should](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) because that is the appropriate and accepted way to do things and gives your end users the power they need to change and modify things if they so choose.

Beyond that, the best you MAY be able to do is use the `SHORTINIT` constant. Define it in a custom php file, then require `wp-load.php` and do what you need to do. `SHORTINIT` stops most of the WordPress core from being loaded.

```
<?php
define('SHORTINIT', true);
require '/path/to/wp-load.php';
// you'll have the basic API here, including `get_option`. Do stuff.
```

If you do this outside the WP core, you'll have to *guess* where `wp-load.php` may be -- you won't have any `ABSPATH` contant to guide you. That's a risky bet unless you're in full control of the system. In other words, if this is a custom, not publicly-released thing, go for it. Otherwise, use `admin-ajax.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Another Method is to add this code into `functions.php` (or in plugin), without need of `require '/path/to/wp-load.php'`... but it will not be as faster as `SHORTINIT` :

```
// EXAMPLE
function MyFuncion(){
    if (isset($_POST['mynamee'])) { echo get_option('my_nm');}
}

//===================Then====================
//1) Execute directly
MyFunction();
//========OR=========
//2) Hook into the EARLIEST ACTION:  
add_action('muplugins_loaded', 'MyFunction',1);
```

p.s   NEVER FORGET TO GUARD and FILTER THE REQUESTS from HACKING!!!