# Connecting to wordpress database in my application

Tags: database

I am creating a wordpress site that will give accounts to people that want to be contributors/authors of a cause that people can donate too. We will approve/deny causes of approved authors

Our backend developer is going to create a system that will allow people to donate to these causes by creating an account. The 'back end' will be completely coded from scratch by us, and the wordpress site will only act as a marketing site for these causes. These will be two different websites.

What the backend developer needs though, is access to the wordpress database. So if an author creates a new cause, our system will see that, and create a new page accordingly.

Is this possible? I don't know much about wordpress database set up. What credentials would I need to give him?

Comment: In response to my answer, you state you are trying to do this using .NET with C#.  As such, your question is out of scope for this site as it lacks a WordPress aspect.

Answer (score 1):

What you likely need is the function [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).  In your backend (not the WordPress backend, just so we're clear), you'll need to do a minimal load of WordPress to allow [`wp_insert_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to work.  You can do this by `define( 'SHORTINT', true )`.

Some additional reading on doing a minimal load of WordPress:

- [Load minimum WordPress environment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47863/load-minimum-wordpress-environment)
- [Ajax takes 10x as long as it should/could](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/ajax-takes-10x-as-long-as-it-should-could)
- [Minimal wordpress load for only `get_option` to work (because ajax...)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103896/minimal-wordpress-load-for-only-get-option-to-work-because-ajax)

In these questions you will also find information how to do this asynchronously, should you desire to do it that way.

Comment: Can i do this on a .Net application? We write our websites using C#

Comment: No.  This is a PHP action.  You will need to craft custom SQL queries to do anything without PHP.  Look into replicating the functionality of `wp_insert_post()`, as it will give you an idea of what format all the data needs to be in for WordPress to interact with it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You should without a doubt use the [WordPress XML RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API). No need for direct database connections and crafting manual queries that might break on future updates.

Not to mention any plugins/themes you use on your WordPress site that depend on       database-related actions/filters will function as normal.

This is the whole reason why an API like this exists. It's what the iOS/Android WordPress apps use, among many other popular 3rd party products that interact with your WordPress site.